# How do I create a new list based on multiple lists within a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to define a function that takes a dictionary with multiple lists as values and creates a new list for each index position. I am able to do it one at a time with my current function. But would like to make it so all lists are created with one function call. Thanks for any help :)

```
league_standings = {'Brett': [9, 6, 7, 8, 3, 7, 7, 5], 'Matt B': [6, 3, 6, 3, 8, 11, 10, 8],
                    'Will/Derek': [6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6], 'Bryan': [5, 6, 6, 7, 11, 6, 6, 6],
                    'Sean': [11, 9, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6], 'Joey/Brian': [4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 8, 8, 6],
                    'Tim': [4, 8, 10, 3, 6, 5, 8, 8], 'Adam': [3, 7, 3, 10, 10, 6, 3, 4],
                    'Michael': [7, 9, 6, 8, 6, 9, 10, 5], 'James/Adam': [9, 5, 6, 6, 9, 3, 7, 8],
                    'John': [8, 7, 9, 7, 4, 9, 6, 8], 'Matt R': [6, 7, 6, 10, 10, 5, 4, 8]}

def elim_px(player_dict):
    season = []
    for k,v in player_dict.items():
        season.append(v[0])
    ss = sorted(season)
    bottom_four = ss[:4]
    print(bottom_four)
    stinkers= []
    for k,v in player_dict.items():
        for i in bottom_four:
            if k in stinkers:
                continue
            elif i == v[0]:
                stinkers.append(k)
    print(stinkers)
```

Comment: What would be your desired output?

Comment: a list of each index position so [9,6,6,5,11,4,4,3,7,9,8,6] would be the first list return. then it would move to index[1] and return the list [6,3,7,6,9,4,8,7,9,5,7,7]

Comment: Still I don't get it, where do you get those numbers? Could you provide a minimal example in you question?